# Swift - Delay in Status Bar Icons Loading

Tags: ios, swift

I added the following methods into my view controller to change the color of the status bar icons to white.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

The view loads and the icons appear white as expected, but after a significant delay (up to 10 seconds). The view loads fine and 10 seconds later the icons pop up, often one by one.

I've added breakpoints into xcode and see the viewDidLoad is called before viewWillAppear, I was lead to believe it was meant to be the other way around. Could this be the issue?

I have also tried adding

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

into the viewDidLoad() method and the app is unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the code you have written `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` after the `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```